# Simplifying a radical equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I'm lost on how to simplify this.

> Simplify:
>   $$\frac{\sqrt[\large 4]{144x^9y^8}}{\sqrt[\large 4]{9x^5y^{-3}}}$$

OK So I think I got it.

$$\frac{\sqrt[\large 4]{144x^9y^8}}{\sqrt[\large 4]{9x^5y^{-3}}} = \left(\frac{{144x^9y^8}}{{9x^5y^{-3}}}\right )^{1/4}$$

You can break that down like this -I think-:

$$\sqrt[\large 4]{16x^4y^{11}}$$

And then finally:

$$2xy^2\sqrt[\large 4]{y^3}$$

EDIT - You can go even further (Thanks amWhy):

$$2xy^{\large \frac{11}{4}}$$

Comment: Your work suggests you are almost there! If you follow Cameron Buie's suggestion you can likely complete the problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, recall that

$$ \frac{\sqrt[\large4]{144x^9y^8}}{\sqrt[\large4]{9x^5y^{-3}}} = \sqrt[\large 4]{\frac{144x^9y^8}{9x^5y^{-3}}} = \left(\frac{144x^9y^8}{9x^5y^{-3}}\right)^{1/4}$$

Now, use the ***["laws" of exponents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties)*** to simplify the rational expression, (the fraction inside parentheses), and then take distribute the exponent $1/4$ over the factors remaining after simplifying.

**ADDED:** You are almost there: you can also write the exponent of $y$ as a fraction. Recall that $\;\;(y^a)^b = y^{ab}.\;$ In your case, $\,a = 3$, and $\;b=1/4$:

$$2xy^2\sqrt[4]{y^3} = 2xy^2\left((y^3)^{1/4}\right) = 2x y^2 \left(y^{3/4}\right) = 2x\left(\color{blue}{\bf y^{\left(2 + \frac 34\right)}}\right)\quad ?$$

$\color{blue}{\bf \left(y^cy^d = y^{(c + d)}\right)}$

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, Don! Nice work!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:  Start by using the fact that $$\frac{\sqrt[4]{a}}{\sqrt[4]{b}}=\sqrt[4]{\frac ab},$$ and see what you can do on the inside of the radical. Then use the fact that $\sqrt[4]c=c^{1/4}$ with exponent rules. Don't forget that $16=2^4.$

**Edit**: Bingo! Nicely done.

Comment: No problem. It may be worth noting that we have to be a bit cautious about the domain of such an expression. In this case, for it to make sense, we needed both $x,y>0$. Obviously neither one of them can be $0$ if we want the expression to make sense. The numerator doesn't make sense if $x$ is negative, so it has to be positive. Then the denominator only make sense if $y$ is positive....

Comment: ... Suppose that the expression had been $$\frac{\sqrt[4]{144x^{10}y^8}}{\sqrt[4]{9x^6y^{-3}}}.$$ Again, we can't let $x$ or $y$ be $0$, but this time we needn't assume that $x$ is positive unless the problem tells us otherwise. (We still need $y$ to be positive so that the denominator makes sense.)...

Comment: ...Then we proceed in a similar fashion, for the most part. $$\begin{align} \frac{\sqrt[4]{144x^{10}y^8}}{\sqrt[4]{9x^6y^{-3}}} &= \sqrt[4]{\frac{144x^{10}y^8}{9x^6y^{-3}}}\\ &= \sqrt[4]{16x^4y^{11}}\\ &= (16x^4y^{11})^\frac14,\end{align}$$ and so far it all looks the same....

Comment: ...Then $$\begin{align} (16x^4y^{11})^\frac14 &= 16^\frac14(x^4)^\frac14(y^8)^\frac14(y^3)^\frac14\\ &= 2(x^4)^\frac14y^2\sqrt[4]{y^3},\end{align}$$ but since $x$ may be negative, the best we can do at that point is $$ 2(x^4)^\frac14y^2\sqrt[4]{y^3}= 2|x|y^2\sqrt[4]{y^3}.$$ This is because for a positive number $a$, we define $a^\frac14$ to be the **positive** number $b$ such that $b^4=a.$ Of course, if the problem tells us to assume that $x$ and $y$ are positive, we don't have to worry about this at all.